# Tumblr API change and the downfall of certain apps

Tags: api, tumblr, photos, posting

I've searched endlessly for answers, and I just cannot seem to find anything!

I use an app (Mac) called Hyperimage for my Tumblr blog.

Since the developer has completely abandoned this app (not returning any customer service emails, fixing this problem, ignoring a refund request via PayPal until I had to complain, etc.) I cannot figure out how I could possibly fix the API, myself?

I'd be very grateful if I could be pointed in the right direction!

Thank you!

Comment: I'm on a PC but I downloaded their DMG and extracted it with 7zip and I'm looking at some decoded application files and it looks like they're using the first version of the API which is deprecated and virtually obsolete. I don't think there's going to be any simple fix here. It's going to need to be completely re-built to use Tumblr API V2 with X-Auth (most likely) and that's going to be a chore. I see things like `tumblr.com/api/dashboard` and that, as far as I know, hasn't been available for a while.

Comment: I was wondering already why HyperImage on Tumblr failed on my new Mac. Thanks for this post! Very sad. When it would work I would even buy it. Good I tried it first out.